# General: Best function name for returning AND values

Tags: .net, function, xor

I want to design a function that returns values that can be AND / ORed.

My attempt is:

```
Public Function getCompatibleValue(ByVal uIndex As Integer) As Integer

    Dim i As Integer = 0

    If uIndex = 0 Then
        i = 0
    ElseIf uIndex = 1 Then
        i = 1
    ElseIf uIndex = 2 Then
        i = 2
    ElseIf uIndex = 3 Then
        i = 4
    ElseIf uIndex = 4 Then
        i = 8
    ElseIf uIndex = 5 Then
        i = 16
    ElseIf uIndex = 6 Then
        i = 32
    ElseIf uIndex = 7 Then
        i = 64
    ElseIf uIndex = 8 Then
        i = 128
    End If

    Return i

End Function
```

But I am neither sure that the name "getCompatibleValue" is good nor that my function logic is very efficient.

Perhaps somebody could share his thoughts on this.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Learn how to use the << operator in VB.NET

Comment: Hans, I guess you have a lot of wisdom to share, but it wouldn't hurt giving more real-world advices. There are some people who can learn more from real-word-code than just theoretical advices. Please don't take it as an offense. I do know that you think that people learn more by exploring something themselves, but on the other hand there are people who explore something AFTER they got the solution. Please don't take this as an offense. I truly admire your skills and knowledge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to have a function in the first place. You can do this directly with the [exponentiation operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh100ckf.aspx):

```
i = If (uIndex = 0, 0, 2 ^ (uIndex - 1))
```

This will give you the value as a `Double`, but you can then cast it to `Integer`.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have a great idea for a naming?

Comment: @tmighty: I don't think that should be a method at all.

Comment: Please imagine the following situation: I have a list of files that the user wants to import. A file may already have been imported, it may have already been imported but deleted, etc. So there are some stati that the file might have. I want to show the files in a grid. They are shown in different sections according to their status. In this case, I would run a for-next-statement and see if the file's status belongs to a getCompatibleValue(i). I hope I could express it adequately, but I guess you understood it right away.

Comment: @tmighty: It sounds like you want an [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h84wky1.aspx), which you could call `FileStatus`.

Comment: Could you be more specific, please?

Comment: @tmighty: I don't think I can do a better job than the manual or any other related tutorial that explains what enums are and how to use them.

Comment: Is there no specific name for the 0, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, etc. thing?

Comment: @tmighty: They are powers of 2. However, their name should tell not what they are, but what they represent.

Comment: Yeah, I know. What I am - because of the language difference - not sure how that should be called. Not that good at English to know the proper function name.

Answer (score 0):

Switch is your friend. And for naming the method I guess it would help to have some context about your intent with it.

Comment: I don't see what you mean by "Switch". I do understand what a Switch statement is but I don't know in which way it could help me here.

Answer (score 0):

Because nobody else suggested something, I want to suggest "getExpontent". 
This is not language specific, tells the user what the function will do.
I have chosen the lower case "get" because I read somewhere that each void and function should start with a lower case letter.